# How to make repaint for JDialog in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jdialog

How to make repaint for JDialog in Swing?
If I click on convert button in JDialog I need to change GUI design of JDialog but it's not happening? Is their any solution?

```
    _convertAction = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String para = new String(); 
            _task.setBookTypeId(13);
             initComponents();
           //   validate();
           //   repaint();
            setVisible(true);
        }
      };
```

I'm setting booking type id is 13 .

```
if(_task.getBookTypeId()== 1){
    String colnames[] = {"Leg","Departure", "Date","Time", "Arrival","Date", "Time","How","Aircraft","PIC","Copilot"};
    MyTableModel mytablemodel = new MyTableModel(colnames);
    legdetailsTable = new JTable(mytablemodel);
    legdetailsTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
}else {
    System.out.println("Brokered booking table");   
    String   colnames[] = {"Leg","Departure", "Date","Time", "Arrival","Date", "Time","How"};
    MyTableModel mytablemodel = new MyTableModel(colnames);
    legdetailsTable = new JTable(mytablemodel);
    legdetailsTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
}
```

Using Id I'm changing componenents in initcomponents method.

Comment: @Jonas  If the OP posts an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html), it guarantees that the relevant code is present.  But until they solve the problem, most people *don't know what the relevant code is.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Window of the current  Component or any Component and than call `repaint()`.

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor( this ).repaint();
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
legdetailsTable = new JTable(mytablemodel);
```

add

```
legdetailsTable.setModel(mytablemodel);
```

You recreate JTable but the new one isn't added to layout